# service fabric actors best practices

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I Have a service fabric that will handle requests for document export, each export request will be treated separately (there is a connection to database and a there is a call for external webservice to generate document and send mail).

The service fabric will contain a stateless service that will expose an action "ExportDocument" to handle these requests.

Each export request can take between 1 and 10 min to generate a document. My concern is how to guarantee the performance, the concurrency and ensure a good workload distribution across all cluster nodes (in parallel).

I thought about using service fabric actors(IExportRequestActor) because it's great for handling many small parallel operations. So my webapi stateless service will instantiate an new actor instance per HttpRequest (my webapp can handle a million of http requests.) is this a good idea to use Actors ? or simply use a webapi stateless service (a thread per HTTP request).

Comment: Where is the longest time spend? Would that be the external service generating the document and sending the email?

Comment: It's my webapp that generate document and send email, but it connect to some external service and database to get some more informations. 
my controller call :

**IReportingDomainService.ExportDocument(exportRequest)** : all the business logic is in this method and it use other services  **IEmailService**, **IDocumentService**.. 
to generate document and send email. 

So my Idea is to change **IReportingDomainService** to **IReportingDomainServiceActor** and this actor call 
IReportingDomainService.ExportDocument(exportRequest)